# Find partial matches of words in pandas column of URLs, directly after https://

Tags: python, pandas

Basically, I have a dataframe where one column is a list of names, and the other is associated URLs that are related to the name in some way (sample df):

```
   Name                    Domain
'Apple Inc'             'https://mapquest.com/askjdnas387y1/apple-inc', 'https://linkedin.com/apple-inc/askjdnas387y1/', 'https://www.apple-inc.com/asdkjsad542/'     
'Aperture Industries'   'https://www.cakewasdelicious.com/aperture/run-away/', 'https://aperture-incorporated.com/aperture/', 'https://www.buzzfeed.com/aperture/the-top-ten-most-evil-companies=will-shock-you/'
'Umbrella Corp'         'https://www.umbrella-corp.org/were-not-evil/', 'https://umbrella.org/experiment-death/', 'https://www.most-evil.org/umbrella-corps/'
```

I'm trying to find the URLs that have the keyword or at least a partial match to the keyword directly AFTER either:

```
'https://NAME.whateverthispartdoesntmatter'  # ...or...
'https://www.NAME.whateverthispartdoesntmatter' # <- not a real link
```

Right now I'm using `fuzzywuzzy` package to gain the partial matches:

```
fuzz.token_set_ratio(name, value)
```

It works great for partial matching, however the matches aren't location dependent, so I'll get a perfect keyword match but its located somewhere in the middle of the URL which isn't what I need like:

```
https://www.bloomberg.com/profiles/companies/aperture-inc/0117091D
```

Comment: you can check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521625/quicker-way-to-perform-fuzzy-string-match-in-pandas#56521804

Comment: You're making this more complicated than it needs to be. You simply want a regex with cpature group to capture the leading `https://(www\.)?`, then split on following '.' or '-', then test for `.startswith` on the lead word. No need for fuzzywuzzy, it's overkill, it'll slow you down, and give false-positives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using `explode/unnest string`, `str.extract` & `fuzzywuzzy`

First we will unnest your string to rows using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51752361/9081267) function:

```
df = explode_str(df, 'Domain', ',').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then we use regular expressions to find the two patterns with or without the `www` and extract the names from them:

```
m = df['Domain'].str.extract('https://www.(.*)\.|https://(.*)\.')
df['M'] = m[0].fillna(m[1])
print(df)


                  Name                                             Domain                      M
0            Apple Inc       https://mapquest.com/askjdnas387y1/apple-inc               mapquest
1            Apple Inc      https://linkedin.com/apple-inc/askjdnas387y1/               linkedin
2            Apple Inc             https://www.apple-inc.com/asdkjsad542/              apple-inc
3  Aperture Industries  https://www.cakewasdelicious.com/aperture/run-...       cakewasdelicious
4  Aperture Industries        https://aperture-incorporated.com/aperture/  aperture-incorporated
5  Aperture Industries   https://www.buzzfeed.com/aperture/the-top-ten...               buzzfeed
6        Umbrella Corp       https://www.umbrella-corp.org/were-not-evil/          umbrella-corp
7        Umbrella Corp             https://umbrella.org/experiment-death/               umbrella
8        Umbrella Corp          https://www.most-evil.org/umbrella-corps/              most-evil
```

Then we use `fuzzywuzzy` to filter the rows with a higher match than `80`:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

m2 = df.apply(lambda x: fuzz.token_sort_ratio(x['Name'], x['M']), axis=1)

df[m2>80]
```

---

```
            Name                                        Domain              M
2      Apple Inc        https://www.apple-inc.com/asdkjsad542/      apple-inc
6  Umbrella Corp  https://www.umbrella-corp.org/were-not-evil/  umbrella-corp
```

---

**Note** I used `token_sort_ratio` instead of `token_set_ratio` to catch the `umbrella` and `umbrella-corp` difference

---

Function used from linked answer:

```
def explode_str(df, col, sep):
    s = df[col]
    i = np.arange(len(s)).repeat(s.str.count(sep) + 1)
    return df.iloc[i].assign(**{col: sep.join(s).split(sep)})
```

Comment: This is perfect, and works, however I forgot the to mention that Domain column has at least 3 different domains within it, so this does perfect at find partial/exact matches but it also keeps the other domains that accompany the exact matches

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, could you edit your question accordingly so I can see what you mean @SebastianGoslin

Comment: Edited with new answer, please try to ask your question correct in one go next time :) @SebastianGoslin

Comment: quick question, how would I drop the rows that don't contain the keyword at the beginning, since they are still being added to the dataframe.

Comment: `df = df[m2>80]` @SebastianGoslin

Comment: super late question, I'm still running into issues where some of the retrieved domains are throwaways like `mapquest` or `linkedin` is there a way to modify this to where the matched word after `https://` or `https://www.` is only the name, and if not, to not include it?

Comment: Sorry, but you cannot keep asking new questions in the comment. This one is answered. Feel free to post a new question and link it here, so I can help you @SebastianGoslin