# ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

[Sample Code]

```
d = {
   'country': ['IN', 'USA', 'USA', 'IN'],
   'username': ['abi.g', 'pugal.g', 'jan.g', 'jacob.h'],
   'email': ['abi@gmail.com', 'pugal.g@yahoo.in', 'jan232@gmail.com', 'jacob@hoi.com'],
   'ClusterID': ['', '4', '5', '9']
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)

data = [
   ['USA', 3490.89, 'qcx_taskid85_duns250437449', '3'], 
   ['JA', 1211, 'Pugal Gandi', '4'], 
   ['USA', 3455.00, 'Janani Khannan', '6']
]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['country', 'salary', 'name', 'ClusterID'])

df1.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df1.loc[df1['ClusterID'] == df2['ClusterID']]
```

[image]
[image]

**Qns:** How to compare/filter the two columns using .loc, while the **no. of records are different** in pandas?

Thanks,

Comment: are you looking for `df1[df1['ClusterID'].isin(df2['ClusterID'])]` or `df1.merge(df2,on='ClusterID',how='outer',indicator=True,suffixes=('','_y')).query("_merge=='both'")[df1.columns]` but the first one is better and readable

Comment: @anky Thanks for the solution. Here, I have two other doubts.. A). `.isin()` only works for an `exact match`.. Is there any way that we can do for `partial search` (e.g partial string match, instead of number?)? B). The direct condition on `.loc(df1==df2)` will works only if the total no. of rows on both datasets are equal?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521625/quicker-way-to-perform-fuzzy-string-match-in-pandas#56521804

Answer (score 1):

Try this >>

```
df1.loc[df1['ClusterID'].isin(df2['ClusterID'])]
```

Both `df1['ClusterID']` & `df2['ClusterID']` are series. Equating two series within `loc` method will throw the exception. Instead, calling `isin` method will give `bool` outputs and hence for all `True` values you will get the corresponding output with `loc` method.