# Merging data frames on column with string partial match

Tags: python

I am attempting to merge two data frames on the column "Name". The names are relatively the same. The merge is not working because there are discrepancies between the names due to special characters, missing suffixes, and nicknames. Any ideas?

df1

| Name | Performance |
| --- | --- |
| Matt Cole Jr | 89 |
| Steve Smith | 72 |
| DJ Watson | 91 |
| Amar'e George | 92 |
| Steve Nurkić | 84 |
| Charles Long | 87 |
| Nic Kitch | 73 |

df2

| Name | Year |
| --- | --- |
| Matt Cole Jr. | 2023 |
| Steve Smith III | 2022 |
| D.J. Watson | 2021 |
| Amare George | 2020 |
| Steve Nurkic | 2021 |
| Charles Long Jr. | 2022 |
| Nicolas Kitch | 2023 |

Desired result:

| Name | Year | Performance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Matt Cole Jr. | 2023 | 89 |
| Steve Smith III | 2022 | 72 |
| D.J. Watson | 2021 | 91 |
| Amare George | 2020 | 92 |
| Steve Nurkic | 2021 | 84 |
| Charles Long Jr. | 2022 | 87 |
| Nicolas Kitch | 2023 | 73 |

I was thinking this could work but the code was taking way too long to execute:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

dfm = pd.DataFrame(df2["Name"].apply(lambda x: process.extractOne(x, df1["Name"])) .tolist()])
```

I also tried this but it didn't match the names correctly:

```
import difflib
from functools import partial
#the below function is inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56521804/9840637
def get_closest_match(x,y):
    """x=possibilities , y = input"""
    f = partial(
    difflib.get_close_matches, possibilities=x.unique(), n=1,cutoff=0.5)

    matches = y.astype(str).drop_duplicates().map(f).fillna('').str[0]
    return pd.DataFrame([y,matches.rename('Name')]).T

temp = get_closest_match(df2['Name'],df1['Name'])
display(temp)
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: are all names in `df1` also present in `df2` and vice versa?

Comment: @Stuart yep they are

Answer (score 0):

[rapidfuzz](/questions/tagged/rapidfuzz) has [`.cdist()`](https://maxbachmann.github.io/RapidFuzz/Usage/process.html) which will score everything in parallel:

```
import rapidfuzz

scores = rapidfuzz.process.cdist(df1['Name'], df2['Name'], workers=-1)
max_score = df2['Name'][scores.argmax(axis=1)]

df1.merge(df2, left_on=max_score, right_on='Name', how='left')
```

```
               Name         Name_x  Performance            Name_y  Year
0     Matt Cole Jr.   Matt Cole Jr           89     Matt Cole Jr.  2023
1   Steve Smith III    Steve Smith           72   Steve Smith III  2022
2       D.J. Watson      DJ Watson           91       D.J. Watson  2021
3      Amare George  Amar'e George           92      Amare George  2020
4      Steve Nurkic   Steve Nurkić           84      Steve Nurkic  2021
5  Charles Long Jr.   Charles Long           87  Charles Long Jr.  2022
6     Nicolas Kitch      Nic Kitch           73     Nicolas Kitch  2023
```